# How do I use JS String.replace and replace with a part of a bracket group using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```js
string
  .replace(/^1[xyz]/g, "$1")
  .replace(/-1[xyz]/g, "-$1")
  .replace(/ 1[xyz]/g, " $1");
```

where `string` is a math expression. I want `$1` to be replaced with x, y, or z, depending on which letter it matched in the brackets. This should replace all occurences in the string.  How do I make it replace properly?

Examples:

- `1x` → `x`
- `-1x` → `-x`
- `5x + 1y` → `5x + y`
- `1x - 1z` → `x - z`
- `11x + 21y` → `11x + 21y` (only replaces 1, not 11, 21, etc.)

Comment: Another option to consider would be to use an actual expression parser, which will avoid a lot of headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
\b1([xyz])
```

- `\b1` A word boundary, then match 1
- `([xyz])` Capture group 1, match one of `x` `y` or `z`

In the replacement use group 1.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k1LYiT/1)

```js
const pattern = /\b1([xyz])/g;
[
  "1x",
  "-1x",
  "5x + 1y",
  "1x - 1z",
  "11x + 21y"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " => " + s.replace(pattern, "$1")));
```